# Get Sitecore Items Sorted By Creation Date

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to get some Sitecore items and then sort them by their creation date with newest items first.

I have the following code (snippet):

```cs
itemID = Constants.BucketIds.NEWS;
Item pressItem = context.GetItem(itemID);
var pressChildItems = context
    .SelectItems("/sitecore/content" + pressItem.Paths.ContentPath + "/*")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Created]);
foreach (Item childItem in pressChildItems)
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

I am getting the following error back:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

I am not sure how I am supposed to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not order by `Field`, sort by its value. Remove `.Fields` from your line:

```cs
var pressChildItems = context
    .SelectItems("/sitecore/content" + pressItem.Paths.ContentPath + "/*")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Created]);
```

Dates are stored as `yyyyMMddHHmmss...` strings, so sorting by value as string will give you exactly the same effect as getting date value from field and ordering using the date.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.

Comment: My answer is only about proper ordering. You should definitely have a look at @jammykam answer and use `ContentSearch` instead of `Sitecore Query`.

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like you have your items in a Bucket, you should really use the `ContentSearch` API (and limit the results if you are using them on the front-end since a bucket could potentially contain thousands of items).

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

List<Item> ResultsItems = new List<Item>();
SitecoreIndexableItem bucket = Context.Database.GetItem(Constants.BucketIds.NEWS);

using (var searchcontext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(bucket).CreateSearchContext())
{
    IQueryable<SearchResultItem> searchQuery =
        searchcontext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
                                        .Take(10);
    SearchResults<SearchResultItem> results = searchQuery.GetResults();

    // fetch the Sitecore Items if you do not want to work with the SearchResultItem
    foreach (var hit in results.Hits)
    {
        Item item = hit.Document.GetItem();
        if (item != null)
        {
            ResultsItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, his query returns children of the root item only, so I'm guessing it's not really a bucket (it's naming only). But totally agree, use `ContentSearch` instead of `Sitecore Query`. Just add `.Where(x => x.Parent == itemID)` condition to the querable and *voilla*.